# How to easily make a chart with this info in Json?

Tags: php, json, charts, bar-chart

Im trying to find an easy way to make a bar-chart with information retrieved for the database behind my website.

Im using *Js and PHP 7*, most of the libraries I tried are js/jQuery like *JsCharts* or *CanvasJs*, but i'm looking to implement a simple bar chart that works fast, without me having to read tons of api's without many examples for my use case.

How can I implement a simple bar chart with the data below?

myData:

```
{
      "area": "a33",
      "production": 255
  },{
      "area": "a31",
      "production": 324
  },{
      "area": "a58",
      "production": 389
  },{
      "area": "a51",
      "production": 121
  },{
      "area": "a28",
      "production": 185
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually there's a recent service ([wannacharts.com](http://www.wannacharts.com)) that works like an api tool, and you only send the Json and they return a chart in png url or a json with a base64 image of the chart.
you have to create your account and they give you a user_id, apikey, etc..

inside there is a chart designer where you must define some paramters of your chart.

the you can make a post to the url with a json like this:

```
{
    "provider_id":3222,
    "chart_id": 412,
    "api_key":"####api-key####",
    "data": [{
      "area": "a33",
      "production": 255
  },{
      "area": "a31",
      "production": 324
  },{
      "area": "a58",
      "production": 389
  },{
      "area": "a51",
      "production": 121
  },{
      "area": "a28",
      "production": 185
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of javascript fiddlery you can make your own bar chart without much effort.

I made a vertical one here.
Just play with the styles, use the widths to represent production. You can even calculate it around to percentages if you prefer.

Take a look at the styles I implemented. I also used jQuery because it makes life easier, but it can also be implemented by plain javascript.

```js
+function(json) {
  // Where the bar chart should go.
  var $wrap = $('#barwrap');
  
  // These are our dummy objects. Prepared here so we can simply clone them
  var $barrow = $('<div class="bar-row">');
  var $label = $('<label class="bar-label">');
  var $bar = $('<div class="bar">');
  
  // I use map here because it provides a nice scope to work in with 
  // scoped variables.
  json.map(function(el) {
      // cloning the dummy objects
      var $br = $barrow.clone();
      var $l = $label.clone();
      var $b = $bar.clone();
      
      // putting the name into the object
      $l.text(el.area);
      // setting the width of the bar chart. 
      // You could implement a percentage calculation here
      $b.width(el.production);
      // Setting the value as text
      $b.text(el.production);
      // Add the label first so it will always be left
      $br.append($l);
      // add the bar so it will be right
      $br.append($b);
      // add label + bar to the html page
      $wrap.append($br);
  });
}([{
      "area": "a33",
      "production": 255
  },{
      "area": "a31",
      "production": 324
  },{
      "area": "a58",
      "production": 389
  },{
      "area": "a51",
      "production": 121
  },{
      "area": "a28",
      "production": 185
  }]);
```

```css
#barwrap {
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
}
/** setting a bar row to be always 100% wide, and to never align to the side of another element */
.bar-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    clear: both;
}
/** The label is just a 50px element for containing the name of the data point */
.bar-label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 2em;
}
/** The width of the actual bar is set by the javascript code **/
.bar {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: white;
    /** aligning the text to the right for visual effect **/
    text-align:right;
    padding-right: 5px;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="barwrap">
  
</div>
```